# Apache Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

We are using Apache 1.3.19 and have started our first foray into mod-rewrite.

We would like to convert a URL structured like so:

`http://somesite.com/us/en/bc/somePage.jsp`

to:

`http://somesite.com/bc/somePage.jsp?isoCountryCode=us&isoLanguageCode=en`

Unfortunately we have run into a brick wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [ref](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/).  The 1.3 version of the Apache HTTP Server, which is no longer maintained, and has been declared **"end of life"**.  It really is time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([_A-Za-z-]+)/([_A-Za-z-]+)/([_A-Za-z-]+)/(.*)$ $3/$4?isoCountryCode=$1&isoLanguageCode=$2
```

I hope that will help ;)